# ERROR al crear un dataframe con datos de un objeto XTS y dar nombres específicos a las columnas

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

Saludos querida comunidad

He creado el siguiente objeto XTS **test_30**

```
> head(test_30)
                    x
2017-12-01 00:30:00 0
2017-12-01 01:00:00 0
2017-12-01 01:30:00 0
2017-12-01 02:00:00 0
2017-12-01 02:30:00 0
2017-12-01 03:00:00 0
```

Por motivos de mi proceso necesito convertir este objeto XTS en un dataframe, lo que hago de la siguiente forma:

`df_test_30 <- data.frame(fecha_hora = index(test_30) - 1800, precipitacion = coredata(test_30))`

Sin embargo, las columnas del dataframe creado **df_test_30** no tienen el nombre que le he asignado, como ven arriba, asigné el nombre *fecha_hora* a la primera columna y *precipitacion* a la segunda columna. En la primera columna *fecha_hora* no hay problemas con el nombre, sin embargo, a la segunda columna no se le asigna el nombre *precipitacion* que he indicado, se le asigna *x*.

El caso es que antes, al hacer esto mismo no tenía ningún problema con los nombres, pero ahora se me presenta este problema.
Bueno, de todas formas, luego cambio el nombre de la siguiente manera:

`names(df_test_30)[names(df_test_30) == 'x'] <- 'precipitacion'`

Con esto, finalmente queda como quiero. Pero no entiendo porque no funciona de la otra forma

Agradezco su ayuda, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema seguramente es este:

```
> class(coredata(test_30))
[1] "matrix" "array" 

> colnames(coredata(test_30))
[1] "x"
```

---

`coredata()` retorna una matriz con una columna y con nombre y `data.frame` respeta este nombre por encima del que le indicas. La solución podría pasar por convertir la matriz en un vector simple:

```
df_test_30 <- data.frame(fecha_hora = index(test_30) - 1800, precipitacion = as.vector(coredata(test_30)))
```